# Add multiple classes with ng-class, where one of the classes is conditional

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I got this code:

```
ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}"
```

It works but I would like too add the 'key' value as a class too, Ive tried:

```
ng-class="[{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}, key]"
```

But that wont work, does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

If you always want `key` to be added as a class:

```
ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol, key: true]"
```

or you can just put it into a `class` attribute with `{{}}` interpolation.

```
ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}" class="{{key}}"
```

Just for completeness, if you only want to include it if it's equal to `selectedCol`:

```
ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol, key: key == selectedCol}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, key: true and key: key == selectedCol will just add the class 'key' and not the value. You woud have thought class="{{key}}" would work and it almost works. But for some reason, other classes like ng-scope ng-binding ui-resizable, wont be added if I go with the class="{{key}}"....No idea why

Comment: Ah... you're right about the `key:true`: it will add the class `key`. Not sure about the other missing classes though.

Comment: Can you post the details about why you need the other classes on this element, and what problems are causes by them not being on the element?

Comment: Why would be quite a long post, and some of them seems to be added by default, so not really sure. Anyway, Ive done some looking around and found this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4807, so I guess you cant really do this yet...I did however found another solution, its not as nice, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/XVAcd/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could handle this using `$scope` methods to define those dynamic class names. This would look something like this:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selectedCol = 3;
$scope.key = 3;

// dynamic ng-class values
$scope.selectedHeader = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedCol === $scope.key)
        return 'header-selected';
    else
        return false;
};

// selected header definition for ng-class
$scope.headerKey = function () {
    return 'header-' + $scope.key;
};
```

**View:**

```
<header ng-class="[ selectedHeader(), headerKey() ]">
    <h1>Header element</h1>
</header>
```

**Result:**

```
<header ng-class="[ selectedHeader(), headerKey() ]" class="header-selected header-3">
        <h1>Header element</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
// single class  
<div ng-class="{'myclass' : condition}">  
</div>  
  
// multiple class  
<div ng-class="{'myclass1': condition1, 'myclass2': condition2}">  
 some content  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
  ng-class="{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}" class="{{key}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, and as I commented on the other answer:You woud have thought class="{{key}}" would work and it almost works. But for some reason, other classes like ng-scope ng-binding ui-resizable, wont be added if I go with the class="{{key}}"....No idea why

Comment: You mean to add directive as `class`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is: `ng-class="{ {{key}}:{{key}} }"`

Also keep in mind that css classes should not begin with a number, so you may need to prefix your key value.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because { selectedHeader : key == selectedCol } will be evaluated as an object and not as a string:

```
ng-class="[{selectedHeader: key == selectedCol}, key]"
```

The following code work, it will add the classes 'selectedHeader' and value of key:

```
ng-class="[key == selectedCol ? 'selectedHeader' : '', key]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class="{{key}} ng-class:{'selectedHeader': key == selectedCol};
```